# Tramsposing large data

Tags: large-data

I am working on UKbiobank data and I need to transpose a very large .csv file with 13615 columns and 456781 rows. File size is 132.4GB and unfortunately, avilable packages lead to OOM error! I am working on SLURM with following preamble:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --mem=150G
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --time 72:00:00
```

The entire file must be included as I want to go for PCA and it's not possible to use chunks from the original data.
Any help would be appreciated.